# Array index out of Range in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexoutofrangeexception

Hi i am trying to print elements of array in reverse order but i am getting error like

> Array index out of Range.

Can u guys help me out? I am posting my code below

```
import UIKit

class DecimalToBinaryViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!


@IBAction func binaryNumber(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var myArray = [Int]()
     var number = textField.text.toInt()
    var num = Int(number!) // for converting optional Int? to Int
    var remainder:Int
   var condition = false
    while condition == false
    {
        remainder = num % 2
        myArray += [remainder]
        num /= 2
        if num == 0
        {
         condition = true
        }
    }
   var size = myArray.count
    for var i = size; i >= 0; i--
    {
     println( myArray[i])
    }


}
```

Comment: `for item in myArray.reverse() { print(item) }`

Comment: You should post your (working!) code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in swift are zero indexed. This means that when you have array count as X, the highest index you can access is `X-1`.

You should make this change to your program

```
var size = myArray.count - 1
```

Comment: thanks.Can you tell me how i am gonna reverse array element permanently?

Comment: Check out the code here at https://www.weheartswift.com/arrays/ under the section `Reverse`. They've posted their solution as well.